# selenium cucumber text inside a span

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber

```
 <div class="tabs-container">
    <div class="wizard-tab active-tab">
  <a class="tab-link-1" href="#">
    <div class="number-circle">1</div>
     <span class="tab-text">Personal Info</span>
</a>  <div class="active-arrow"></div>
</div>

    <div class="wizard-tab inactive-tab">
  <a class="tab-link-2" href="#">
    <div class="number-circle">2</div>
    <span class="tab-text">Address</span>
</a>  <div class="active-arrow"></div>
</div>

    <div class="wizard-tab inactive-tab">
  <a class="tab-link-3" href="#">
    <div class="number-circle">3</div>
    <span class="tab-text">Identity</span>
</a>  <div class="active-arrow"></div>
</div>

    <div class="wizard-tab inactive-tab">
  <a class="tab-link-4" href="#">
    <div class="number-circle">4</div>
    <span class="tab-text">Consent</span>
</a>  <div class="active-arrow"></div>
</div>

  </div>
```

I would like to select or check the text in the spans, for the first one I am successful by using :

```
Then element having css "span.tab-text" should have text as "Personal Info"
```

now I want to do it for all the tabs, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did this , and it worked :

```
Then element having css "div.tabs-container div.active-tab span.tab-text" should have text as "Personal Info"
```

Answer (score 0):

start from the class attribute of <**a**> tag.

```
   Then element having css "a[class$='link-1']>div>span" should have text as "Personal Info"
   Then element having css "a[class$='link-2']>div>span" should have text as "Address"
   Then element having css "a[class$='link-3']>div>span" should have text as "Identity"
   Then element having css "a[class$='link-4']>div>span" should have text as "Consent"
```